# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, jdbc, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I am getting this error when compiling my java program

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Then I knew that I should add the path of `mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar` to the java classpath. I am using Windows XP, I edited the classpath in the controlpanel/system/enviromental variables

the classpath was : `.;C:\j2sdk1.4.2_16\jre\lib;`

so now it became : `.;C:\j2sdk1.4.2_16\jre\lib;C:\Program Files\mysql-connector-java-3.1.144`

however, i still get the same error, moreover, when I type set classpath in the cmd ( just to check what is the current classpath ) i get :

```
CLASSPATH= .;C:\j2sdk1.4.2_16\jre\lib;
```

can anyone help me fix this ?

Comment: maybe you missed .jar extension while editing classpath.

Comment: Did you restart cmd after making the change?

Comment: As a side note, I wouldn't add the classpath to mysql-connector to the CLASSPATH variable. You should simply specify this dependency directly: java -cp "C:\program files\mysql-connector..." com.yourcompany.MainClass

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to put the full path to the jarfile in the classpath (including the filename):

```
.;C:\j2sdk1.4.2_16\jre\lib;
C:\Program Files\mysql-connector-java-3.1.144\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar
```

As Hippo said, you have to restart `cmd` after changing that. If it doesn't work, launch your program like this:

```
java -cp ".;C:\j2sdk1.4.2_16\jre\lib;
C:\Program Files\mysql-connector-java-3.1.144\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar"
my.class.Name
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Open Netbeans IDE
2. Right-click your Project.
3. Select Properties.
4. On the left-hand side click Libraries.
5. Under "Compile" tab - click Add Jar/Folder button.
6. Select Downloaded "mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar" file ([Download Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) from dev.mysql.com)
7. Click OK
8. Run Again... Its work.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to copy the mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin file in the Libraries of the project folder. Everything will work fine.