# ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, asterisk, mysql-connector

I wrote java class to connect `mysql` database and insert data to database on my `centos` installed pc.(this java file called by asterisk program using `AGI`). but I got below exception at runtime.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

How could I solve this ?

Comment: This question/Answer should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233049/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I solved my question. when I run the asterisk program with AGI server, I added mysql connector `classpath` as below.

```
java -classpath asterisk-java-0.3.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar:. org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer
```

Comment: This works.. It is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

you need this jar file: mysql-connector-java-{version}.jar

e.g. 
http://findjar.com/jar/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.9/mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar.html

Comment: i have added `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar` and set `class path`. but still having problem.