# Getting Error when connection to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have downloaded the following:

- `mysql-essential-5.1.65-win32` from [this MySQL Dev link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=409234)
- MySQL Connector `mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.zip` from [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=408558)

Now I have started programming with `Eclipse`. I have made simple java class like below,

```
public class MySQLAccess {

      private static Connection connect = null;
      private Statement statement = null;
      private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
      private ResultSet resultSet = null;

      public static void main(String[] args){

          try{
              Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance (); 

          }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
              System.out.println("Error : "+e);
        }         
      }   
}
```

I have also made a folder "lib" in my Java project and I have put that `mysql-connector` `jar` over there. But when I run this program it can't find mysql I get the following error in the console :

```
Erro : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Can someone please tell me where I have made the mistake? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Putting the full jar-file path in your classpath and restarting cmd (if you are running from cmd) should work-

See here- [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233049/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Answer (score 0):

If it your java application project then you put jar file into jdk  library path ext folder.

```
eg:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\jre\lib\ext
```

you will get path from your project class path .